# Executing query based on the result of another query

Tags: ms-access

I want to execute one query based on the result of another query

```
Select count(*) as totalcount from (select * from emp)
If(totalcount >0)
Select * from emp1
Else
Select * from emp2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Access there are no stored procedures like in T-Sql so you have to be imaginative.

One possible method would be:

```
SELECT * FROM emp1 WHERE DCount("*","emp")>0
UNION
SELECT * FROM emp2 WHERE DCount("*","emp")=0
```

Here, we are using a `UNION` query which returns results from both tables, but using contradicting `WHERE` clauses to actually only return the results of one table.

Comment: Thanks for reply to mm Mett.

Comment: Here is the problem is:My two tables are different structures, then how can i make union of two tables.

Comment: Then you cannot do it this way. Do you have to do it all in a query? If you use VBA it will be a lot easier.

Comment: please let me know how to write vba code in ms access

Comment: i was created click event on my tab

Comment: can i execute query to find count of records and then can i check the condition?

Comment: Where are you displaying results?